# TensorFlow GPU failed to load/import

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I installed TensorFlow-GPU 1.11.0 and when I try to import it, I'm getting error. I'm stuck at this point.
My system specifications are,

- Windows 10 64bit
- GeForce GTX1080
- Graphic Driver 385.54
- Python 3.5.4
- Cuda Toolkit 9.0
- CuDNN 7.3
- Visual Studio 2015

Don't know what is missing. Kindly help me regarding this issue. I will be thankful. Below is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Ahsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Ahsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Ahsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Ahsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ahsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Ahsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Ahsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Ahsan\AppData\Loca
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can display code correctly by putting 4 spaces at the start of a code line.

Answer (score 0):

```
 pip install tensorflow --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

This command worked for me previously in a similar case. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ashutosh, It will for GPU? because you didn't write word GPU

Comment: have you tried it? If yes, was there any change in the output?